# Pyspark - concatenate two dataframes based on one field

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, left-join

I have two dataframes:
The data is too large to use pandas, so I need to do this in Pyspark.

df1:

```
 col 1 | col 2 | col 3|
 12345 | asd   | zxc  |
 12345 | qwe   | dfg  |
 12345 | ert   | fgh  |
```

df2:

```
 col 1 | col 2 | col 3|
 54321 | asd   | poi  |
 54321 | qwe   | lkj  |
 54321 | ert   | mnb  |
 54321 | ytuyeye | jfg|
```

I want to concatenate these dataframes with the same columns so the width of the table doesn't expand and I'm only taking data in df2 that has a matching col 2. In the above example, I would expect the result to have 6 rows.

In other words, df1 is a snapshot and df2 is a snapshot at a later date where I only want to join in records that are present in df1. I've tried join and union and haven't had any luck. Thanks in advance

I got the answer:

```
df2_x = df2.alias('b').join(df1.alias('a'), ['col2'], "inner")\
                                             .select("*")
df3 = df1.union(df2_matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

Imports:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W, types as T
```

Method 1, using join and union:

```
out1 = df1.unionByName(df1.alias("df1")
          .join(df2.alias("df2"),on='col 2',how='inner').select("df2.*"))
```

Method 2 using union and then a window to count partitioned over col 2 and only keep if count>1

```
w = W.partitionBy("col 2")
out2 = df1.unionByName(df2).withColumn("Counts",F.count("col 2").over(w))\
.filter("Counts>1").drop("Counts")
```

---

Lets look at the Physical plans:

---

```
out1.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Union
   :- Scan ExistingRDD[col 1#173L,col 2#174,col 3#175]
   +- Project [col 1#192L, col 2#193, col 3#194]
      +- SortMergeJoin [col 2#426], [col 2#193], Inner
         :- Sort [col 2#426 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col 2#426, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#1557]
         :     +- Project [col 2#426]
         :        +- Filter isnotnull(col 2#426)
         :           +- Scan ExistingRDD[col 1#425L,col 2#426,col 3#427]
         +- Sort [col 2#193 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col 2#193, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#1558]
               +- Filter isnotnull(col 2#193)
                  +- Scan ExistingRDD[col 1#192L,col 2#193,col 3#194]
```

---

```
out2.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [col 1#173L, col 2#174, col 3#175]
   +- Filter (Counts#451L > 1)
      +- Window [count(col 2#174) windowspecdefinition(col 2#174, col 2#174 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS Counts#451L], [col 2#174], [col 2#174 ASC NULLS FIRST]
         +- Sort [col 2#174 ASC NULLS FIRST, col 2#174 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col 2#174, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#1588]
               +- Union
                  :- Scan ExistingRDD[col 1#173L,col 2#174,col 3#175]
                  +- Scan ExistingRDD[col 1#192L,col 2#193,col 3#194]
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these options worked. The first threw an error that the column name could not be found in the data (it is there) and the second returned a blank dataframe.

Comment: @pand19 This means there is a difference between column names of both the dataframes, what is the output of `set(df1.columns).intersection(df2.columns)`, if this returns blank, you might carefully want to check the column names. ideally the length of intersection should be same as length of df1.columns. Alternatively you can also check `set(df1.columns).difference(df2.columns)` and you will find this returning values of columns which doesnot match

Comment: the column names are sourced from the same base table. Running that line correctly returns all of the columns in my dataframes. 

In the first option, I tried substituting a different appropriate variable that the error said was in the table. After running, it threw the same error for the new variable.

The difference line, returns a blank set.

Comment: @pand19 this works for me on your sample datasets. can you check if this works for you for the sample data?

Comment: AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "col2" among (col1, col3);'
same error. (I removed the spaces in the column names for this exercise)

Comment: @pand19 its an issue with column names in your daataframe v/s the code which you need to figure, the solution should run fine once you have figured that and the variable which you are using in your original usecase....

Comment: I am certain my column names match. 

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (12345, "foo", 123),  
        (12345, "bar", 345),
        (12345, "bat", 567),
    ],
    ["col1", "col2", "col3"]  
)
    
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (54321, "foo", 543), 
        (54321, "bar", 980),
        (54321, "bat", 876),
        (54321, "mat", 462),
    ],
    ["col1", "col2", "col3"] 
)

Comment: @pand19 well in that case, there must be other elements in your actual code which I am missing. Sorry but I tested again and this works for your original post.